# What message converter can i use instead of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()

Tags: spring

I'm not using Application JSON I am using HTML_TEXT as content 
so what message converter should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter** : This converter supports all media types.

Better not to override any default settings, Let spring configuration to do its magic by applying suitable message converter based on content type.

Other useful message converters :

- SourceHttpMessageConverter
- StringHttpMessageConverter
- ResourceHttpMessageConverter
- AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
- ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="yourValue",produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
```